# InvalidOperationException with unit testing using Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, rhino-mocks

I have implemented following unittest:

```
[Test]
public void ReportGeneratorOneThreadTest()
{
    var logger = this.mockRepository.StrictMock<ILog>();
    var generator = this.mockRepository.StrictMock<IReportGenerator>();
    this.manager = new ReportGeneratorManager(logger, new Guid(), 1, null);
    this.reportGeneratorThread = new ReportGeneratorThread(
        logger, generator, this.manager.CancellationTokenSource.Token,
        this.manager.getPermission, this.manager.Action);
    using (this.mockRepository.Record())
    {
        Expect.Call(() => this.reportGeneratorThread.Start());
    }          

    using (this.mockRepository.Playback())
    {
        this.manager.StartManager();           
    }
}
```

My ReportGeneratorManager class is responsible for creating an instance of ReportGeneratorThread class and it calls the Start() method of ReportGeneratorThread afterwards.

I'm expecting that the Start() method of ReportGeneratorThread class is called by the manager, once I start the manager:

```
 this.manager.StartManager();
```

but an exception is thrown in Expect.Call which is:

```
 Invalid call, the last call has been used or no call has been made.
```

It's clear from the logs that the start method is actually called in ReportGeneratorThread class, so the test should be passed, but keeps throwing the exception. How do I handle this issue ?.

Comment: It would be better to refactor the test and / or code so that the test doesn't have to work with actual threads.  Those are usually problematic in testing environments.  Or, you'll have to ensure that at the end of your tests, that 1) everything shuts down gracefully and 2) no threads are running after each test step.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that I'm using tasks instead of threads. Even though the class name is ReportGeneratorThread, is starts tasks using the Start() method.

Comment: Same difference, Tasks will get run on real threads from a thread pool, so the advice still applies.

Comment: I think the issue might be that the reportGeneratorThread.Start() method is called by a task instead of the main thread ?.

Comment: @OsmanEsen you use `Expect.Call` on a non mock method. This is the problem... (`Expect.Call(() => this.reportGeneratorThread.Start());`)